# Drag and Drop from Files app fails with 257 file protection error

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I've got Drag and Drop working (iOS 11) for Safari / Mail etc, however when I try and drag & drop an image from my iCloud Desktop (using the Files app), I get a `couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it` error.

I thought Drag & Drop deals with file protection issues in the background at 'drop' time. How can I access a file I'm trying to share with my app explicitly? Here's the code that fails

```
itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { item, error in
      var data: Data? = nil

      if item != nil && (item is URL) {
        if let item = item as? URL {
          do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: item)  // <--- fails 
          } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
          }
        }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do.. had to wrap it around

`item.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`

and

`item.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`